# Having trouble connecting to OpenStreetMap

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I have recently delved into playing around with the OpenStreetMap package but I cant seem to be able to download tiles eg

```
conf.map = openmap(c(60,-90),c(-45,45),type="osm")
```

will give me this error

> Could not open Bing aerials attribution metadata. failed loading 3/2/2
>   Connection timed out: connect

I am not sure if this is a port issue as it is not my PC or if it is an issue with OSM but I couldn't find a solution anywhere and couldn't even find the port OSM uses to download map tiles.

If anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening that would be awesome!!

Comment: Why would asking for an OpenStreetMap map (type="osm") give an error about trying to get Bing aerial information? Sounds odd. Looking at the code the only point that error occurs is after trying to get some XML metadata from dev.virtualearth.net, via http and the usual port 80 - nothing odd there at all. Do you need to specify an http proxy for that PC? I bet its not configured for Java...

Comment: Usually this error occurs for example at the JOSM editor, if for a certain zoomlevel the bing layer is added and it needs time to figure out the attribution. But AFAIK the R framework uses vector data?  
Your area is really big, please try a very smal part of the world like an city district.

Comment: Hmm I think it may be as you have said Spacedman, Ill have to check as I dont have Admin rights to this computer, and I found that this error was consistant so I dont think it would be the area size as I tried other cities and got the same error. Cheers guys I couldnt find anything on the net about this problem. Ill update you on whether it fixed the issue.

Comment: The java proxy was the issue just had to assign it properly, cheers for the help guys!!!

Comment: How did you do that?! I have the same issue with packages that use Java.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Any body knows how to set java proxy settings?