# Why does leaflet output grey map?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I run simple examples of leaflet package in R like:

```
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)

>somePlace <-ggmap::geocode("Vienna")  
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Vienna&sensor=false  
>somePlace 
lon      lat
1 16.37382 48.20817
>leaflet(somePlace) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
```

Map shows grey space with a blue marker:

[image]

No trace of OSM spatial visualisation. Could you point out where is the problem?

Thanks in advance for constructive discussion!

My configuration:
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10),
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit),
Windows Server 2012 x64 (build 9200), ggmap_2.6.1, leaflet_1.0.1.

Similar problems (but without a suitable solution):
[R leaflet package produces blank (grey) map [Ubuntu 14.04]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070637/r-leaflet-package-produces-blank-grey-map-ubuntu-14-04)
[R leaflet RStudio Viewer blank (grey) map [Windows 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647872/r-leaflet-rstudio-viewer-blank-grey-map-windows-7)

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187926/leaflet-output-is-grey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to my own question is that the local firewall settings prevented me from downloading the tiles from OSM. The way how to solve it was to set proxy (from within R > [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy)). The con of this solution is that the viewer still doesn`t deliver tiles as the proxy settings at the moment do not apply to RStudio Viewer. Although, the leaflet output appears properly in browser, therefore works also with Shiny Apps. 
Thanks for the support contributing to the solution!

Comment: I have had similar issues, I have to use a proxy service to get past our silly security settings to access tiles, and stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working in R 3.2.3 and also in RStudio. Let it load, it takes time. Before loading it looks like the screenshot you have pasted above.I am using Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Thnx for your answer. It's loading now 30 min while I try to find a solution. How long can it take?

Comment: @Patrik: it takes not even 1 minute on my side. I am not working on server. SO I have no idea how it would work there. In both R and R Studio, it just loads in 30 seconds.

Comment: As pointed out [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187926/leaflet-output-is-grey), the issue seems to be related with the local Java installation @SowmyaS.Manian.

Comment: The java problem was solved & the problem persits therefore a solution still needed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Patrik still not able to see map??

Comment: No issue is persisting. I seems it has something to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532675/having-trouble-connecting-to-openstreetmap.
That is assigning properly java proxy setting.

Comment: Most of them having this problem are windows 7 people..and some in ubuntu. Will see if anywhere they have reported on how to solve this isssue. You can try running the same in other windows machine like 8 or 10.

Comment: Try resizing the width to 100% resizing might load, not sure though

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
addTiles()
```

with

```
addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)
```

Seems to force leaflet to provide the tiles to knitr's html.

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work with `providers$CartoDB`?